# Cannot find right project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am having a problem with VS. I have installed it and I cannot find the type of project I was using.
Before, inside the project, I had the folders App_Data, App_Start, fonts, Scripts and Web.config, but now when I make a new project, any kind of project I choose (Api Web Asp.Net Core, App Web ASP.Net Core(MVC) and all the others...) does not create this folders and I am not able for example to add a connection string. Am I missing some installation or what?
Thank you so much!

Comment: That is the "old way" of dong websites.  in NET Core those folders dont exists any more

Answer (score 0):

The folders and files listed belong to .NET Framework, which is not installed by default on newer versions of VS.

To install the .NET Framework templates, open the Visual Studio Installer > Modify > Individual Components > and make sure that `.NET Framework project and item templates` is checked

Comment: @Kazan which project template are you using? Try searching for .NET Framework in the search bar, maybe you are using the wrong template (the ASP.NET Core one for example)

Comment: I am trying all the templates :P But nothing... If I search for .NET Framework, I have:
- App Windows Form(.NET Framework)
- App WPF(.NET Framework)
- App console(.NET Framework)
and others I don't need...

Comment: Simon, somehow I have found a solution. I have installed from individual components "More templates (previous version)" and now I have the template I was using before. :) I don't know if it is a good practice or not, but...